# Android GpsStatus always has zero satellites

Tags: java, android, gps, android-location, android-gps

I'm trying to get the satellites used in a GPS fix to get more information, but the GpsStatus.getSatellites() method always returns an empty iterator, even though I can get the location's latitude/longitude/altitude just fine.

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

if (location != null) {

    //get location coordinates
    mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    mLongitude = location.getLongitude();
    double altitude = location.getAltitude();
    Log.d("test2", "lat : " + mLatitude);
    Log.d("test2", "long : " + mLongitude);

    //get satellite data
    GpsStatus gpsStatus = locationManager.getGpsStatus(null);

    int satellites = 0;
    int satellitesInFix = 0;
    int timetofix = gpsStatus.getTimeToFirstFix();
    Log.d("test2", "Time to first fix = " + timetofix);
    for (GpsSatellite sat : gpsStatus.getSatellites()) {
        if(sat.usedInFix()) {
            satellitesInFix++;
        }
        satellites++;
    }
    Log.d("test2", "Satellites: " + satellitesInFix + "/" + satellites);
}
```

All I get in the debug log is the following, over and over again:

```
09-06 18:42:48.093 6842-6842/com.android.example.gpstest D/test2: lat : 39.509401143731274
09-06 18:42:48.093 6842-6842/com.android.example.gpstest D/test2: long : -9.064780960816815
09-06 18:42:48.094 6842-6842/com.android.example.gpstest D/test2: Time to first fix = 0
09-06 18:42:48.095 6842-6842/com.android.example.gpstest D/test2: Satellites: 0/0
```

I already tried with multiple devices, thinking it might be some quirk with a particular model, but they all have the same issue, so it seems like my code isn't right. What do I need to do to get the satellites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you haven't started GPS.  getLastKnownLocation does not turn on GPS, it only returns a cached value, if any.  You need to requestLocationUpdates to do so.

Comment: I'm calling requestLocationUpdates() on the activity's onResume method, and the code I posted is inside the onLocationChanged method.

Comment: WHy would you ever call getLastKnownLocation in onLocationChanged?  It passes you the last location

Comment: Also, from the getGpsStatus documentation:   "Retrieves information about the current status of the GPS engine. This should only be called from the onGpsStatusChanged(int) callback to ensure that the data is copied atomically. The caller may either pass in a GpsStatus object to set with the latest status information, or pass null to create a new GpsStatus object."

Comment: Ah, that might be it. But, I just implemented onGpsStatusChanged and it's not capturing any status change events, even when I disable and enable location services.

Comment: Have you called addGpsStatusListener()?

Comment: Silly me. I really need to slow down when reading the documentation. Thanks a lot for the help.